# How to Mount Multiple CephFS on Client-Node?

Tags: ceph

I'd Created three CephFS and try to Mount it on Client node but didn't find any way to mount specific one Cephfs. I'd tried

> mount -t ceph mon-node:/ /mnt/apachefs/ -o mds_namespace=webfs,secret=`ceph-authtool -p /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring`

But it fails, Is there any other way to Mount Multiple File systems on Client node with use of **kernel Driver**, **mount.ceph** or **ceph-fuse**?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to specify multiple CephFS by following options.

- `-o mds_namespace` ... kernel Driver (mount -t ceph)
- `--client_mds_namespace` ... ceph fuse (cephf-fuse)

I am pretty sure that `-o mds_namespace` did not work due to old kernel version. If you are using CentOS7, please test it with ceph-fuse 12.2.4 or later version with (`--client_mds_namespace`). It worked fine on my env.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Debian based system, you can install **ceph-fs-common** package with apt, like: apt-get install -y ceph-fs-common.

Comment: I'm using Centos7 and already installed ceph-fs-common, any other ways to mount multiple file system like we use multiple rbd's on client node. I want to mount multiple cephfs same as multiple rbd devices.

Answer (score -1):

```
ceph fs volume create nextcloud [<placement>]
ceph fs volume create okd-admin [<placement>]
#/etc/fstab
### one
10.10.20.6:6789:/folder1  /USERDATA ceph  name=admin,secretfile=/etc/ceph/secret.key,fs=nextcloud,noatime,_netdev  0  2
### two
10.10.20.5:6789:/folder2  /mnt/cephfs ceph  name=okd-admin,secretfile=/etc/ceph/secret-openshift.key,fs=openshift,noatime,_netdev  0  2
```

Comment: What does this do and how does this answer the question?